# How to pass parametric prevState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a variable to prevState in React and I'm wondering how to use a computed variable for the prevState in Javascript syntax.

the case is that I have a field for starting date and one for the ending date and I want to use the same function to set state after the input is entered.

first function:

```
handleStartDayChange( e ) {
  const state = e.target.name 
  const day = Number( e.target.value )
  this.setState( prevState => ({ 
    [ state ] : changeDay( 
      moment( prevState.startingDate ), day
    )
  }) )
}
```

second function:

```
handleEndDayChange( e ) {
  const state = e.target.name 
  const day = Number( e.target.value )
  this.setState( prevState => ({ 
    [ state ] : changeDay( 
      moment( prevState.endingDate ), day
    )
  }) )
}
```

What I need: a function that can replace both of them like this:

```
handleDayChange( e ) {
  const state = e.target.name 
  const day = Number( e.target.value )
  this.setState( prevState => ({ 
    [ state ] : changeDay( 
      moment( prevState.[ state ] ), day
    )
  }) )
}
```

Comment: `prevState.[ state ]` is incorrect syntax, you'll need to remove the period character (`prevState[ state ]`)

Comment: So you want to execute the exact same code but in the one function? That's a copy/paste job...

Comment: @JackBashford no , i was wondering how to use `prevState[ state ]`  as @Titus mentioned

Comment: @Titus tnx! just worked :)